# How to use f3 beforeroute() to check for logged in user, redirect to login and then back to original route?

Tags: php, routes, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to use fat free framework in my application. beforeroute() seems like a logical choice for checking for an active session, if all routes on this path require authentication. I am having trouble trying to find which route the user was attempting to go to before I hijack it and force them to login. 
I feel like there should be an f3 variable, or something simple that I can call within beforeroute() that'll give me information about where they were trying to go, and that I should be able to use f3 to accomplish this, instead of other ways I've done this in php apps (session variable, or sending something as a param in the domain, etc).

Am I missing something about beforeroute()? Should it not be used for this situation? And if not, what is the best practice?

I've tried grabbing the url in a session variable $f3->set('SESSION.previousUrl', $f3->REALM), but since I am always redirecting them to login, the result is always /login.

While I'm at it, can somebody explain the difference between reroute and redirect within f3? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the origin URL to the login route. E.g:

```
function beforeRoute($f3,$params) {
  if (/*user not authenticated*/)
    $f3->reroute('/login?origin='.$f3->PATH);
    // or if you need to preserve query strings:
    $f3->reroute('/login?origin='.urlencode($f3->PATH.($f3->QUERY?'?'.$f3->QUERY:'')));
}
```

Now in your login route, if the user authenticates correctly, reroute it back to the origin URL:

```
function post($f3,$params) {
  if (/*user gets authenticated*/) {
    $f3->reroute(isset($_GET['origin'])?$_GET['origin']:'/');
  }
}
```

As for the [redirect](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#redirect) method, it's a mix between `route` and `reroute`.

For example, `$f3->redirect('GET /oldpage','/newpage',TRUE)` is a shorthand for:

```
$f3->route('GET /oldpage',function($f3){
  $f3->reroute('/newpage',TRUE);
});
```

It's mostly interesting to be used in configuration files, such as:

```
[redirects]
GET /oldpage = /newpage
```

Comment: So we still send it as a param in the domain, huh? I had been hoping that f3 would have made that more elegant, but oh well! thanks for your thorough answer. :)

Comment: Well, F3 doesn't do anything about it. It's up to you. You could as well store it in a session variable, but that sounds overkill for such a simple task.